# Fetching Image location from JSON in NextJS 13

Tags: json, typescript, image, fetch-api, next.js13

So I made me a getData.ts:

```
export async function getData(){
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/projects")
    return res.json()
  }
```

to fetch data similar to this:

```
    "projects":[{
        "title": "Project 1",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "tags": ["example", "notReal", "placeholder", "lol", "rofl"],
        "imageURL": "project1IMG"
    },{
        "title": "Project 2",
        "description": "Description 2",
        "tags": ["you", "get", "the", "idea"],
        "imageURL": "project2IMG"
    },
```

I made a Projects component to contain all my projects (*fragments for some tailwind trickery*):

```
import React from "react"
import { getData } from "@/lib/getdata"
import Project from "./project"

export default async function Test() {
    interface projectType{
        title: string,
        description: string,
        tags: [],
        imageURL: string
    }


    const projects: projectType[] = await getData()
    return (
        <section className="group">
        <div>
            {
                projects.map((project, index) => (
                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                    <Project {...project} />
                    </React.Fragment>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    </section>
      )
}
```

and now I'm kind of stumped how to reference the images from @/public with this method. I can achieve it locally but would like to host my JSON elsewhere but serve the images myself...

And here's the container for each project minus the styling:

```
import Image from "next/image"

type ProjectProps = typeof projectsData[0]

export default function Project({ 
    title, 
    description, 
    tags, 
    imageURL,
}: ProjectProps){
    return (
       <div>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{description}</p>
        <ul>
            {tags.map((tag: string, index: number) => (
                <li
                key={index}>{tag}</li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      <Image 
        src={imageURL}
        alt="placeholder"
        width="100"
        height="100"  
        /> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

(*bonus points for fixing my awful typescript declaration*)

Tried many things but feel like I'm missing a key piece of logic here...

Answer (score 0):

**Current fix**

JSON data references the file:

```
"imageURL": "project1.png"
```

and I'm importing like so:

```
src={`/${imageURL}`}
```

It does the trick...